# Understanding two Multivibrator models

Tags: microchip, cadence, mems-microphone

I simulated the two multivibrator models in CMOS technology using the cadence tool. I was expecting the **model 2** with Schmitt trigger(ST) will show robustness in  PVT (Process Voltage temperature) analysis as compared to **model 1** due to ST. But this was not the case both the Models shows the same response to PVT variation analysis means their outputs were stable under varying PVT conditions. Could anyone address my queries:

1. Is Schmitt trigger in Model 2 having an edge over model 1?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some noise to your sim. A slow edge with noise going into the NAND gate will cause some additional oscillations during the switching time.
The Schmitt trigger will greatly improve upon that.

Comment: Thanks, @Aaron for your suggestion. Adding noise will help to further investigate  the performance of both models